# Eliminar un registro luego de aceptar la alerta enviada por Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede eliminar o realizar cualquier otra función con `php` luego de que el usuario presione aceptar al alert de `Javascript`
Por ejemplo

```
 if(isset(POST['eliminar'])){
    "alerta JS" 
    if(alertaJs){ 
        ClaseEliminar:: metodo_eliminar();
    }
 }
```

Se puede realizar algo así o cuáles son las opciones ? Claro que el código no tiene mucho sentido , pero es solo para representar si es posible realizar ese flujo y esa inserción de `JS` y `PHP`

Comment: de hecho ya hay un funcion confirm() de javascrip que puedes usar

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar un confirm y poner una llamada ajax si el usuario presiona OK

```js
if (confirm('Eliminar elemento')) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/remove_something.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            item_id: "id",
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Hacer algo
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```